# Confused about GridView and INamingContainer?

Tags: c#

I have a nested GridView.  In order for me to find the nested GridView, I have to do a FindControl on the Parent GridView, but I was under the impression that you only need to do this if the parent control implements INamingContainer and according to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), GridView does not implement from INamingContainer.  Is there another reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is each row (or cell, don't recall exactly) has its own set of IDs, so it is surely one of those that implement INamingContainer.

Update - its the row: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.aspx

Comment: That was what I was thinking that it had to be something else within the GridView.

Comment: @Xaisoft glad to help, added a link to where it shows the gridviewrow's definition with INamingContainer.

Comment: Yes, I actually just found it also. Thanks.